# How to access jquery plugin from outside the plugin

Tags: jquery

I am trying to call an action on all the plugin associated to an element in my page.

**Basically, if an event is triggered in my page, all the elements with this plugin should do something**

I tried several methods. First I tried to keep an array of all the plugin references on the elements and then call the method but when I instantiate a plugin I can't get the reference so it inserts `undefined` in my array

So, I then tried to remove the plugin and re instantiate it by doing `$(element).data()` but it appears that even if the plugin works, the `data()` method returns an empty object.

I thought jquery would populate this object when I instantiate my plugin on my dom element but it doesn't. Is there anything to do for that?

I am using a plugin I have developed,

```
(function($){

    $.fn.Module = function(action) {

        var obj         = $(this);

        list();

        function list() {
            ...
        }

        obj.find('.update-name').live('click', function(e) {
            // 1. API ajax call
            list() // 2. Reload the current plugin
            // 3. TODO : call the 'list' function of all the plugisn that have been created on elements with class 'notifications'
        });
    }
})(jQuery);

// Create plugins on dom elements with class "tasks", "events" and "notifications"
$(".tasks").Module();
$(".events").Module();
$(".notifications").Module();
```

The part I can't figure out how to do is the "TODO"

Comment: Please add more details about the specific plugin that you are trying to use and some code samples.

Comment: Some code please would be necessary.

Comment: It is a plugin I am developing by myself. That's why I am wondering if there is something specific to add to my plugin. I have added the plugin skeleton if this can help.

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that jQuery automatically links plugins to augmented elements through `data()`. That is not the case, you either have to implement that feature yourself or use a plugin framework that does (such as jQuery UI's widget engine).

Comment: hum ok. So I have changed the title and added an example of what I would like to do (in bold).

Comment: We do not have enough information to provide advice here. Can you add the part of your plugin that augments DOM elements to your question?

Comment: I have added some more code :)